# Glossaries package: smallcaps and uppercase in index does not work

Tags: table-of-contents, glossaries, small-caps

I am using the `glossaries` package in pdfLaTeX. I am trying to

1. use the acronyms written in small caps in the body text

   and
2. for the index, make the first letter of each entry name in the glossary uppercase.

I have already tried to look around but I could not find a solution.

To obtain the glossary I run the command `makeindex` defined as following:

```
"/usr/texbin/makeglossaries" %
```

Normally, I load my entries from 2 external files but I do not think that this is the problem since I get the same issue also after running my MWE. Anyway, to show the commands I'm using I inserted them as comments in the MWE.

Also, I'm not sure if this is important, but I use MinionPro as my main font and KOMA-Script.

My MWE is based on this thread:
http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=9966

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[toc=true,smallcaps,section,nonumberlist,acronym,nomain]{glossaries}
\newglossary{slg}{sym}{syb}{Nomenclature}
% \input{./text/glossary}
% \loadglsentries{./text/symbols}
\makeglossaries
\newacronym{pcm} {PCM} {phase change material}
\newglossaryentry{sym:hfus}{type=slg,sort={pl:h},
                  name = {\null$\Delta H_{fus}$},
                  description={latent heat of fusion}}

\begin{document}
Sample: \gls{sym:hfus}. \gls{sym:hfus}. \gls{pcm}. \gls{pcm}.

    \textsc{This is small caps. PCM pcm }

\renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{\makefirstuc{#1}}
\printglossary[type=slg, style=long, nonumberlist=true]

\renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{\MakeUppercase{#1}}
\printglossary[type=acronym, style=long]
\end{document}
```

Here's the result:
[image: Result of MWE]

The only thing that gets capitalized is Fus from the math environment and I really do not understand how this happens. Everything else (smallcaps option and uppercases of description) is just not working.

Someone can please explain me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you. Note also, that [your name automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Comment: Please **check your code compiles** before posting it. This does not.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about both what you get and what you want. For the acronyms, you want them to all be small-caps in the text and to be what in the list of acronyms? Similarly, what exactly do you want for the nomenclature? You talk about a glossary but you don't seem to have one - just nomenclature and acronyms. Also, what do you mean that `makeindex` is defined as `/usr/texbin/makeglossaries`?! Given that `makeglossaries` calls `makeindex`, I certainly hope you don't mean this literally. Everything gets capitalised here, by the way...

Comment: Incidentally, there is no point in asking for acronyms to be typeset in small-caps if you write them in uppercase.

Comment: Unrelated comment: I think `$\Delta H_{fus}$` really should be `$\Delta H_{\text{fus}}$`, i.e., using `amsmath`'s `\text` for the subscript. Your subscript currently contains the product of the variables _f_, _u_ and _s_.

Comment: @cfr I do not know why you cannot compile my MWE code. I simply copy pasted the one I used to create the result image I posted. What kind of error do you get?

Comment: @cfr I didn't know that if I wrote everything in uppercase the smallcaps option would not work. **So this solves my issue (1)**.
When I used the word glossary I was referring to the Nomenclature and Acronym section. For both, in the respective lists, I would like for the description to have the first letters in uppercase.
About `makeindex`: the friend who thought me the basics, told me to modify the standard command `Makindex` found in _TeXmaker/Preferences/Commands/Makeindex_ from `"/usr/texbin/makeglossaries" %.idx` to the command I posted. For this reason I posted this information too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, your acronyms aren't appearing in small caps because you've defined them using upper case. You said that the upper casing of the description hasn't worked. That's because you haven't made any changes relating to the description. `\glsnamefont` is applied to the name not the description. You need to define a new style that makes the description start with an upper case letter:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[toc=true,smallcaps,section,nonumberlist,acronym,nomain]{glossaries}
\newglossary{slg}{sym}{syb}{Nomenclature}

\makeglossaries

\newacronym{pcm}{pcm}{phase change material}
\newglossaryentry{sym:hfus}{type=slg,sort={pl:h},
                  name = {\null$\Delta H_{fus}$},
                  description={latent heat of fusion}}

\newglossarystyle{long-ucdesc}{%
  \setglossarystyle{long}%
    \renewcommand{\glossentry}[2]{%
    \glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}} &
    \Glossentrydesc{##1}\glspostdescription\space ##2\tabularnewline
  }%
}

\begin{document}
Sample: \gls{sym:hfus}. \gls{sym:hfus}. \gls{pcm}. \gls{pcm}.

    \textsc{This is small caps. PCM pcm }

\printglossary[type=slg, style=long-ucdesc, nonumberlist=true]

\renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{\MakeUppercase{#1}}
\printglossary[type=acronym, style=long]

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: Image of resulting document]

The following defines a style that makes the initial letters of the description upper case:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[toc=true,smallcaps,section,nonumberlist,acronym,nomain]{glossaries}
\newglossary{slg}{sym}{syb}{Nomenclature}

\makeglossaries

\newacronym{pcm}{pcm}{phase change material}
\newglossaryentry{sym:hfus}{type=slg,sort={pl:h},
                  name = {\null$\Delta H_{fus}$},
                  description={latent heat of fusion}}

\newglossarystyle{long-ucdesc}{%
  \setglossarystyle{long}%
    \renewcommand{\glossentry}[2]{%
    \glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}} &
    \Glossentrydesc{##1}\glspostdescription\space ##2\tabularnewline
  }%
}

\makeatletter
\newglossarystyle{long-initcapsdesc}{%
  \setglossarystyle{long}%
    \renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{\MakeUppercase{##1}}%
    \renewcommand{\glossentry}[2]{%
    \glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}} &
    \protected@edef\thisdesc{\glsentrydesc{##1}}%
    \xcapitalisewords{\thisdesc}\glspostdescription\space ##2\tabularnewline
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Sample: \gls{sym:hfus}. \gls{sym:hfus}. \gls{pcm}. \gls{pcm}.

    \textsc{This is small caps. PCM pcm }

\printglossary[type=slg, style=long-ucdesc, nonumberlist=true]

\printglossary[type=acronym, style=long-initcapsdesc]

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: Image of result]

If you have at least version 4.22 of `glossaries`, you can use `\glsentrytitlecase` instead:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[toc=true,smallcaps,section,nonumberlist,acronym,nomain]{glossaries}
\newglossary{slg}{sym}{syb}{Nomenclature}

\makeglossaries

\newacronym{pcm}{pcm}{phase change material}
\newglossaryentry{sym:hfus}{type=slg,sort={pl:h},
                  name = {\null$\Delta H_{fus}$},
                  description={latent heat of fusion}}

\newglossarystyle{long-ucdesc}{%
  \setglossarystyle{long}%
    \renewcommand{\glossentry}[2]{%
    \glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}} &
    \Glossentrydesc{##1}\glspostdescription\space ##2\tabularnewline
  }%
}

\newglossarystyle{long-initcapsdesc}{%
  \setglossarystyle{long}%
    \renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{\MakeUppercase{##1}}%
    \renewcommand{\glossentry}[2]{%
    \glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}} &
    \glsentrytitlecase{##1}{desc}\glspostdescription\space ##2\tabularnewline
  }%
}

\begin{document}
Sample: \gls{sym:hfus}. \gls{sym:hfus}. \gls{pcm}. \gls{pcm}.

    \textsc{This is small caps. PCM pcm }

\printglossary[type=slg, style=long-ucdesc, nonumberlist=true]

\printglossary[type=acronym, style=long-initcapsdesc]

\end{document}
```

With [`glossaries-extra`](https://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries-extra) you can make use of the `glossdesc` attribute:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[section,nonumberlist,acronym,nomain]{glossaries-extra}
\newglossary{slg}{sym}{syb}{Nomenclature}

\makeglossaries

\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short-sc}

\newacronym{pcm}{pcm}{phase change material}
\newglossaryentry{sym:hfus}{type=slg,sort={pl:h},
                  name = {\null$\Delta H_{fus}$},
                  description={latent heat of fusion}}

\glssetcategoryattribute{acronym}{glossdesc}{title}
\glssetcategoryattribute{general}{glossdesc}{firstuc}

\begin{document}
Sample: \gls{sym:hfus}. \gls{sym:hfus}. \gls{pcm}. \gls{pcm}.

    \textsc{This is small caps. PCM pcm }

\printglossary[type=slg, style=long, nonumberlist=true]

\printglossary[type=acronym, style=long]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I now understand the issues, but for some reason I cannot compile your code. I get 2 errors referred both to line 27, saying `! Undefined control sequence \@glsstyle@long-ucdesc ->\setglossarystyle` and also `! LaTeX Error: \glossentry undefined`. I had also an issue with your other post answers. In that case I could compile but I didn't obtain upper case letters in the description.

Comment: @DoubleD It sounds like you need to upgrade your version of `glossaries`.

Comment: Thanks! Would it be possible to capitalize all the first letters only for the acronyms list? To my understanding I thought the command `\renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{\MakeUppercase{#1}}` was supposed to do this, but apparently it does not.

Comment: @DoubleD `\renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{\MakeUppercase{#1}}` just makes the `name` field (the abbreviation in the case of the list of acronyms) appear in all capitals. Do you mean you also want the `description` field (the long form in the case of the list of acronyms) to have initial letters converted to uppercase?

Comment: Yes. If possible, that would be my intention.