# Hyphen in uppercase acronyms in Glossaries

Tags: glossaries, hyphenation, capitalization

I'm using the Glossaries package, and I would like the acronyms to be printed as follows:

- list of acronyms: first letter of each word of an acronym to be uppercase
- running text: first letter of each word of an acronym to be lowercase

The solution presented [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165419/glossaries-package-smallcaps-and-uppercase-in-index-does-not-work?answertab=votes#tab-top) works very well, but I have an acronym with a hyphen, which is recognized as one word ("Air-conditioning"). How can I revise the code so the output is "Air-Conditioning" in the list of acronyms instead of "Air-conditioning"?

My code so far is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,11pt]{report}
\usepackage[nopostdot,nogroupskip,nonumberlist,acronym]{glossaries}

\newacronym{hvac}{HVAC}{heating, ventilation and air-conditioning}

\makeatletter
\newglossarystyle{long-initcapsdesc}{%
  \setglossarystyle{long}%
    \renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{\MakeUppercase{##1}}%
    \renewcommand{\glossentry}[2]{%
    \glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}} &
    \protected@edef\thisdesc{\glsentrydesc{##1}}%
    \xcapitalisewords{\thisdesc}\glspostdescription\space ##2\tabularnewline
  }%
}
\makeatother

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

\printglossary[type=acronym,style=long-initcapsdesc,title={List Of Acronyms}]

\vspace{100pt}
\noindent 
text text text \gls{hvac} text text text

\end{document}
```

And the current output looks like this:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have at least version 2.03 of [`mfirstuc`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mfirstuc) you can enable splitting on hyphens with `\MFUhyphentrue`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,11pt]{report}
\usepackage[nopostdot,nogroupskip,nonumberlist,acronym]{glossaries}

\MFUhyphentrue

\newacronym{hvac}{HVAC}{heating, ventilation and air-conditioning}

\makeatletter
\newglossarystyle{long-initcapsdesc}{%
  \setglossarystyle{long}%
    \renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{\MakeUppercase{##1}}%
    \renewcommand{\glossentry}[2]{%
    \glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}} &
    \protected@edef\thisdesc{\glsentrydesc{##1}}%
    \xcapitalisewords{\thisdesc}\glspostdescription\space ##2\tabularnewline
  }%
}
\makeatother

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

\printglossary[type=acronym,style=long-initcapsdesc,title={List Of Acronyms}]

\vspace{100pt}
\noindent 
text text text \gls{hvac} text text text

\end{document}
```

There's now a simpler way of applying `\capitalisewords` to a field:

```
\newglossarystyle{long-initcapsdesc}{%
  \setglossarystyle{long}%
    \renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{\MakeUppercase{##1}}%
    \renewcommand{\glossentry}[2]{%
    \glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}} &
    \glsentrytitlecase{##1}{desc}\glspostdescription\space ##2\tabularnewline
  }%
}
```

[image: image of result]